# count the number of selections in a multiple-select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple selection list which have more than 5 options, and i want to count the number of selection of the options selected by the user.

How to do it using java script?

I tried the following but it didn't work for me:

```
var x = document.getElementById("preference").count;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: >var x=document.getElementById("preference").count;

Answer (score 28):

Assume `foo` is the id of the select.

If you use normal javasript:

```
var options = document.getElementById('foo').options, count = 0;
for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].selected) count++;
}
```

If you use jQuery:

```
var count = $('#foo option:selected').length;
```

Comment: thankyou,its workinkg fine.Is there any property which can check the number of selections rather than using a for loop,as we use in "checkboxes" where .checked property can be used.?

Comment: @coolmego No, there is no such property. For `checkbox`, yes, use the `checked` property.

Comment: can u suggest a good tutorial for javascript starting from basics.

Answer (score 3):

This did it for me.
`var x = document.querySelector("#preference").selectedOptions.length;`

Comment: Upvote. Vanilla js and no for loop. One-liner is concise.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:selected` selector, like this:

```
$('#example option:selected').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get multiple select boxes user selected options count and their selected names. Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/N6YK8/8/

```
function getCount(){
             var comboBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("select");
             var selected = [];
             for(var i=0,len=comboBoxes.length;i<len;i++){
                    var combo = comboBoxes[i];
                    var options = combo.children;
                    for(var j=0,length=options.length;j<length;j++){
                         var option = options[j];
                         if(option.selected){
                           selected.push(option.text);
                         }
                    }
             }
            alert("Selected Options '" + selected + "' Total Count "+ selected.length);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If < IE8 isn't a concern, you can do a one-liner like `document.querySelectorAll("option:checked")` to get all the selected options.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it works correctly https://jsfiddle.net/Tayssirrr/1ca7mpur/5/

```
enter code here  <script>
         function getCount(){
             var comboBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("select");
             var selected = [];
             for(var i=0,len=comboBoxes.length;i<len;i++){
                    var combo = comboBoxes[i];
                    var options = combo.children;
                    for(var j=0,length=options.length;j<length;j++){
                         var option = options[j];
                         if(option.selected){
                           selected.push(option.text);
                         }
                    }
             }
           // alert("Selected Options '" + selected + "' Total Count "+ selected.length);
                    document.getElementsByName("selectedd")[0].value = selected.length;

         }  
    </script>
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful!

Answer (score -2):

```
function SelectPage(elem)
{
    alert(elem);
}
<select id="page" name="section" onChange="SelectPage(this);" id="num">
    <option value="">Select Section</option>
    <option value="1">Page-1</option>
    <option value="2">Page-2</option>
    <option value="3">Page-3</option>
    <option value="4">Page-4</option>
    <option value="5">Page-5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use this also in your function
`var len = docment.getElementById("num").options;
alert("hello"+len.length);`