# i have a html multiple select box where nothing is selected prior. I need to validate that at least one should be selected either in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

```
<select name="test" size="5" multiple>
<option value="1">widget 1</option>
<option value="2">widget 2</option>
<option value="3">widget 3</option>
<option value="4">widget 4</option> 
<option value="5">widget 5</option>
</select>
```

I need to validate that at least one should be selected.
REMEMBER I DON'T WANT ANY CHANGE IN SELECT OPTIONS.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549770/count-the-number-of-selections-in-a-multiple-select-box

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="test" size="5" id="test" multiple>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
if(document.getElementById("test").value!="")
{
  // some value is selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
if(document.getElementById("selectbox").value)
{
  alert(document.getElementById("test").value);//you will got selected value
}
```

before this give id to your select box, you haven't give any id to select

like

```
<select name="test" id="selectbox" size="5" multiple>
```